# ServiceStack caching users roles and permissions approach

Tags: servicestack

With the AuthFeature / AuthUserSession plugin, we can populate the session with a users roles, permissions, etc in the PopulateSessionFilter on each request.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings), 
                    new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
                    {
                        PopulateSessionFilter = (session, principal, req) => 
                        {
                            //Example of populating ServiceStack Session Roles for EF Identity DB
                            var userManager = req.TryResolve<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                            var user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(session.Id).Result;
                            var roles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
                            session.Roles = roles.ToList();
                        }
                    }, 
                }));
```

Is there way to store this in cache, MemoryCacheClient or Redis depending on what has been configured so do not have to do a database call here, or is it a case of implementing the caching solution in the userManager itself (or whatever repository code is written to get this information)?

Comment: Similar to this https://forums.servicestack.net/t/db-queried-each-time-authusersession-hasrole-haspermission-referenced/3731 but I'm hoping to avoid adding to the JWT token.

Comment: Looks like I can maybe use HostContext.TryResolve<ICacheClient>() to get at the cache.

Comment: Right that's how you can access the registered cache client or you can access the local memory Cache Client with `req.GetMemoryCacheClient()` or `req.TryResolve<MemoryCacheClient>()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included better support for accessing and caching ASP.NET Identity User Roles in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/fc269bf6cc1b8ab949bfecb10b34326bcc18559e). This change is available in the latest v5.4.1 pre-release that's [now on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

```
var userManager = req.TryResolve<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
var user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(session.Id).Result;
var roles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
```

Whilst this works it uses "sync over async" which is discouraged as it's problematic in many use-cases, less efficient than sync and the limited API forces multiple DB calls.

The new `IDbConnection.GetIdentityUserRolesById(userId)` API is now our recommended and more efficient API which resolves the above issues and utilizes a single DB call to fetch just the ASP.NET Identity User Roles.

This is an extension method that works on any `IDbConnection`, to avoid opening a new DB Connection from the connection string yourself you can utilize EF's `ApplicationDbContext` DB Connection in a new scope by adding this to your App:

```
public static class AppExtensions
{
    public static T DbExec<T>(this IServiceProvider services, Func<IDbConnection, T> fn) => 
        services.DbContextExec<ApplicationDbContext,T>(ctx => {
            ctx.Database.OpenConnection(); return ctx.Database.GetDbConnection(); }, fn);
}
```

This provides a generic API that makes it easy to utilize your App context DB connection.

With this you can fetch the User Roles with the more terse and efficient alternative:

```
new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
{
    PopulateSessionFilter = (session, principal, req) => 
    {
        session.Roles = ApplicationServices.DbExec(db => db.GetIdentityUserRolesById(session.Id));
    }
},
```

To avoid hitting the DB on each request you can cache the results by utilizing the local Memory Cache Client with:

```
new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
{
    PopulateSessionFilter = (session, principal, req) => 
    {
        session.Roles = req.GetMemoryCacheClient().GetOrCreate(
            IdUtils.CreateUrn(nameof(session.Roles), session.Id),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            () => ApplicationServices.DbExec(db => db.GetIdentityUserRolesById(session.Id)));
    }
},
```

This will avoid hitting the database to fetch User Roles for this user for **20 minutes**.

The above utilizes the `MemoryCacheClient` which avoids any I/O as it's maintained in memory, to utilize the Registered `ICacheClient` instead, rename `GetMemoryCacheClient()` to `GetCacheClient()`, i.e:

```
new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
{
    PopulateSessionFilter = (session, principal, req) => 
    {
        session.Roles = req.GetCacheClient().GetOrCreate(
            IdUtils.CreateUrn(nameof(session.Roles), session.Id),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            () => ApplicationServices.DbExec(db => db.GetIdentityUserRolesById(session.Id)));

    }
},
```

Comment: Ah that's nice and elegant.  I'd forgotten about the GetOrCreate method on the CacheClient.  Thanks.